# How to exclude lines above a target

Tags: bash, search, grep

I have read multiple posts about how to exclude lines around a grep match, but none addresses it with finality, most find other ways to sort data, and that does not solve similar issues with different data.

i have a file with a recursive output, a command repeated over and over. i want to trim out the 0 results because it is the only constant value, the result hits are an unknown quantity.

the only unique string i can search by needs to have the 4 lines above it excluded no matter what the content of those lines are, and i have not found any post with info generic enough to fit.

this is a conceptual question, there has to be a simple solution, but if an example is needed:

```
Path/Path/Path> search
[results]
[results]
2 entries found
Path/Path/Path> search
[result]
1 entry found
Path/Path/Path> search
0 entry found
```

Comment: I still don't understand what you want as a result from your example.

Comment: Your question is unclear. More specifically this part _the only unique string i can search by needs to have the 4 lines above it excluded no matter what the content of those lines are, and i have not found any post with info generic enough to fit._ awk can do this probably very easy but we would need an example input and example output.

Comment: You want to delete lines with 0 entry found and the path before ?

Comment: how can (awk) remove the 4 lines above a string at all? i gave an example of what my  data source contains. my search string is "0 entry" that is unique because any other line shares the same data as lines that i need to keep. what i need is to remove the 0 entry found results from my data file while keeping everything else. (and i need to exclude the 0 entry results because i won't know in advance what entries will be in the data file, but it will contain many 0 result entries. hence why i need to target those for removal) my output will be everything else.

Comment: yes, ctac, but in my file its 4 lines.and those 4 lines share the same string as the paths of the entries that i want to keep, so i can't search them separately.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand what you look for. Give a example of expected output.

Comment: data set is:
Path/Path/Path> search
[results]
[results]
2 entries found
Path/Path/Path> search
[result]
1 entry found
Path/Path/Path> search
0 entry found

output should be:
Path/Path/Path> search
[results]
[results]
2 entries found
Path/Path/Path> search
[result]
1 entry found

in this example its only one line above the target, but i'll need to be able to remove multiple lines above the target.

Comment: Is that block of text at the end of your question your sample input or expected output? Whichever it is, add the other one too so we have a complete example. If that's your sample input then it's not clear why deleting the 4 lines above the `0 entry found` wouldn't be removing desirable output given your description of what you're trying to do nor is it clear of that matching line is 1 of the 4 to be deleted or not. wrt `how can (awk) remove the 4 lines...` - trivially but we need a clearer picture of your requirements to help you create a solution..

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
# Assumption: The data is in logile.txt

i=0
tac logfile.txt |\
while read -r line; do
   if [[ "${line:0:7}" == "0 entry" ]]; then
        i=0
        continue
   else
       ((i++))
       [[ $i -le 4 ]] && continue
   fi   
   echo "$line"
done | tac
```

output:

```
Path/Path/Path> search
[results]
[results]
2 entries found
```

Comment: `tac | something | tac` may be a reasonable approach (depending on how the OP responds to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55656704/how-to-exclude-lines-above-a-target#comment98011760_55656704)) but see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219 for some of the reasons why that `something` shouldn't be a shell loop.

Comment: Lox, this is mostly good, but it cuts off data at the end (or the beginning because its tac?) can you explain the {line:0:7} and [[$i - le 4]] ? it may need to be tweeked. 
Ed, what i need to be able to exclude or remove blocks of data from my file but the string i use to find the block is at the end of the block of 4 lines. this is my trouble. if you need an example:
INPUT FILE CONTENTS:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
0 entry found
OUTPUT FILE CONTENTS:
1
2
3

Comment: (i also mentioned in my earlier note that my data needs 4 lines removed while the one i left in the example above only showed one line, this was due to spacing)

Comment: ${line:0:7} test if the first 7 character match the pattern "0 entry"

Comment: [[$i - le 4]] test if $i is lower or equal 4